# Unable to get value of selected radio

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of the radio button selected.
My html is:

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="one" />One<br />
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="two" />Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="three" />Three<br />
<a ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getSelectedRad()">Click</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

My jquery is:

```
function getSelectedRad() {
    alert($("input[name='rad']").val());
}
```

I cannot understand what is wrong happening here?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/jhruG/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the value of the first element that is of type 'input' with a 'name' attribute that has a value of 'rad'.

You want a selector that looks like:

```
"input[name='rad']:checked"
```